# Visual Studio does not format source code with implicitly typed array (`new[] {1,}`)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 usually does a reasonable job formatting code, but it seems to have trouble with implicitly typed arrays.

For instance, the input

```
var    x     =    new   [   ]     {
           1    ,
         }    ;
```

gets formatted as

```
var x = new[]     {
           1    ,
         };
```

It seems the `[]` trips VS, because temporarily removing it yields:

```
var x = new {
    1,
};
```

Which looks much better and is what I'm hoping for (after adding the `[]` again or course).

Did I misconfigure VS, or is this a bug perhaps?

Comment: Report the issue on github. Roslyn has many formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, I have submitted a [ticket at github/roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9702).